# How to run a linux command from loadrunner vugen script?

Tags: c, linux, loadrunner, syslog, rsyslog

I am using Linux LGs and I want to use syslog / rsyslog to dump the custom logs from my loadrunner vugen script. For that I tried to run a linux command by using the loadrunner function **int system( const char *string);** but it's not working for me. Do you have any alternative for this?

For your ready reference please check the custom function which I have used for using the syslog / rsyslog.

```
lr_syslog(char *log)
{

lr_param_sprintf("PAR_syslog", lr_eval_string("./syslog %s"), log );

system(lr_eval_string("{PAR_syslog}")); 

return 0;
}
```

and syslog.c is as follows

```
#include <syslog.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
openlog ("loadrunner", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
syslog (LOG_INFO, "customlog - %s", argv[1] );
closelog ();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the function: `syslog()` writes to the log file.  That doesn't seem to be what your trying to perform.

Comment: system() should work on Linux

Comment: is there any follow up or resolution on this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest as an alternative the use or lr_output_message() which will be directed to the output window on your controller.

If you wish to post process these messages in logparser, elk, or splunk you can then export the messages and import them into your favored log analysis tool..... or you can just use the features of Microsoft Access to run queries against the messages using standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could collect system log while perform testing. After tested, you could open test result by LR Analysis and import system log by Import Data function. 
[image: LoadRunner Analysis]

Then you could create Correlation between Response Time and system resource in LR Analysis. And it will help you to analyze performance.
[image]

From this [URL](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/Analysis/106100_c_import_data_tool.htm)，you could find the detailed usage of Import Data.